# Generate random number in .bashrc alias

Tags: bash, random

I'd like to create an alias to run my specs in a random order, like so:

```
alias randspec="rspec --seed $RANDOM";
```

However, the value of $RANDOM ends up being set to whatever value it is when .bashrc is sourced (i.e., not really random when I run the command multiple times).

```
alias randspec="rspec --seed `echo $RANDOM`";
```

...doesn't seem to get it either.  Any ideas?

Comment: `alias randspec="rspec --seed \$RANDOM";` or `alias randspec='rspec --seed $RANDOM';`

Comment: randspec(){ rspec --seed $RANDOM; }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape your `$` so that `$RANDOM` gets evaluated when you invoke the alias, rather than when the alias is defined:

```
alias randspec="rspec --seed \$RANDOM";
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `/dev/urandom` and a hex dumper:

```
alias rand_spec="dd if=/dev/urandom bs=16 count=1 2> /dev/null | xxd -ps"
```

`xxd` is deployed with `vim`

Comment: $RANDOM seems easier, but I'm up-voting since this is a pretty bitching way of doing it as well